# Missing route from docker interface to vpn

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, docker, cisco-anyconnect

The current pandemic has forced me, like most of you I assume, to work from home.
Working from home made me aware of a limitation with my setup. And my lacking networking knowledge is not enough to even find the right answer online.

The problem is routing from docker to anything inside the corporate network which i access using Cisco AnyConnect.

I am running on Arch linux (Kernel: 5.7.5-arch1-1)

These are my interfaces:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether
3: wlp60s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether
5: cscotun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1390 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none 
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether
```

from host:

```
$ nslookup any.corp.address
Server:     10.10.11.10
Address:    10.10.11.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   any.corp.address
Address: xxx.yy.zzz.zzz
```

from docker:

```
$ docker run busybox telnet 10.10.11.10 53
telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.10.11.10): Connection timed out
```

what im trying to say is that the corp dns server is reachable from host (via vpn network interface) but that ip is not reachable from within docker container.

How do I allow traffic that comes out of `docker0` to travel to `cscotun0` ?

Comment: just in case you should provide some network settings in the question: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip rule`